# Why drop-down list outside viewable space of wpf form is not clickable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winforms-interop

I have RadAutoCompleteBox control, with a lot of items and event for item selection `AutoCompleteBoxSelectionChanged`. This event works fine if I select item from drop-down in viewable space of wpf form and it's doesn't works if I select item outside viewable space.
See example:
[image]

Comment: There are known issues in WPF with interoperation between WinForms and WPF components, especially related to event propagation of this kind. Is this WPF control perhaps embedded in a WinForms app?

Comment: Yes, it is WPF plug-in inside WinForms app

Comment: That can be a problem, and is very hard to work around. I believe the window rectangle of the enclosing WinForms app is used in whatever black magic propagates events between the two worlds. A lot of things just don't work smoothly (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, my advice would be to redesign your WPF form so nothing it creates goes outside its rectangle. Hope somebody else can give you better news.

Comment: Is this a Telerik control? Don't they make a WinForms library?

Comment: Yes, this is Telerik control telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox .

Comment: I'm afraid I have experienced the same issue with Infragistics controls and plain vanilla combo boxes when embedded in a WinForms Excel taskpane. For the bother of trying to hack around the issue, it's easier to either redesign the form to have a different layout, or simply stop mixing the WPF and WinForms worlds.